# APP_DEBUG=true is being ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have `APP_DEBUG=true` in the `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://test.dev
```

I've deliberately use incorrect incorrect url (eg: `test.dev/asdsadsa`) which does not in the web.php route file.

I expected to get an laravel debug error when route does not exist

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

However, it keep showing 404 error page (views/errors/404.blade.php) even `APP_DEBUG` is set to true.

What I have tried:

1 - I even tested to make sure laravel can read .env file:

```
Route::get('/', function() { 
  dd(env('APP_DEBUG')); 
});
```

return `true`

2 - `php artisan config:cache` did not fix it.

3 - `chmod -R 777 storage` did not fix it.

Comment: can You provide routes.php and Kernel.php ?

Comment: have you tried setting the value in the app.php file JUST to check?  I've had my .env file ignored before when someone else was wrong

Comment: @num8er http://kopy.io/tcvzN

Comment: did you mean `artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: @dangel I have also tried `artisan config:clear` and that didn't fix it.

Comment: if you have 404 error page it will be displayed , and if you haven't , `NotFoundHttpException` will be displayed.

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN I believe you've won.  I just tried this out and never knew about it.

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN You are right, I have tested it.. I never knew that. Could you post Answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have 404 error page in `views/errors` it will be displayed, and if you haven't, `NotFoundHttpException` will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very late to the game here, but if nothing else worked try clearing all cache and then run:

php artisan optimize:clear

Answer (score 1):

Just add this two lines in your error view, for example in `views\errors\404.blade.php`

```
<?php $e = new Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler(); ?>
<?php echo getenv('APP_DEBUG') == 'true' ? $e->getContent(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException::create($exception)) : ''; ?>
```

This will show the laravel debug error in your custom 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove make sure that Your `App\Exceptions\Handler` does not have in `$dontReport` this line:

```
'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
```

[image: screenshot]

take a look at documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler

and find:

> Ignoring Exceptions By Type
>
> The $dontReport property of the exception handler contains an array of
>   exception types that will not be logged. For example, exceptions
>   resulting from 404 errors, as well as several other types of errors,
>   are not written to your log files. You may add other exception types
>   to this array as needed

Comment: I've just done that now, I have removed `'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'` from `$dontReport` and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Then I don't have any suggestion. It's 5.3 maybe something's changed. Let me know if You'll able to fix that (share Your knowledge). (;

Comment: Check ABDEL-RHMAN answer.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back  yeah, I was thinking about that but due my experience with 5.2, I though that it cannot be so stupid simple (:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .env file in the root folder of the laravel project. If you don't have one, please search how to create laravel .env file and create it.